Estimate the values of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos{nx}}{n}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
I've been asked to evaluate, or at least estimate
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos{(nx)}}{n}\quad\text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}$$
My claim is that for $x=0$ the series diverges since it's the harmonic. $\cos(nx)$ is an even function so i will just work on $x>0$. 
For all intervals of finite length you can estimate the value of $\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ as such:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(nx)\,dx=\frac{2}{\pi n}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})\Rightarrow \\ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}<\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})}{\pi n}\frac{1}{n}\sim\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)$$
So for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the sum is finite. for $x\to\infty$ I want to use the Abel-Dirichlet convergence theorem since I have a decreasing sequence times one whose partial sums are finite. Is there something wrong? if so how do i fix this reasoning, or else how to do this properly? Thank you.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1112534/442

I'm not sure it's the exact same problem, but i'm doing the math now and double checking with the post. Anyway, thank you!

From the series expansion
$$
\log \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^n}{n}, \quad \mbox{for}~ |z| < 1, z  \in \mathbb{C}, 
$$
Treating the series expansion above as formal and evaluating at $z = e^{it}$, and taking the real part, we have an ansatz of $f(t) = \log\Big(\frac{1}{2}|\csc\frac{t}{2}|\Big)$.
Note that the function $f$ is even and in fact $2\pi$-periodic. Therefore, $f$ has a Fourier cosine series
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} a_0 + \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \cos(nx)
$$
where we have
\begin{align*}
a_0 &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \log(\tfrac{1}{2} |\csc(x/2)|) \, dx = 0 \\ 
a_n &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi  \log(\tfrac{1}{2} |\csc(x/2)|) \cos(nx) \, dx = \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
Thus we have the Fourier series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}. 
$$
Regarding convergence, since $f$ is differentiable, except at $x \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$, we immediately have pointwise convergence of the Fourier series except at these points. (On the other hand, at $x = 2n \pi$, $f(x) = \infty$ and moreover the Fourier series is the Harmonic series and diverges as well.)

Thank you, I put some comments re: convergence.

+1 nice answer.

Let $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\cos(kx)}k$, then
$$
\frac d{dx}S_{n}(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)=-\mathrm{Im}(1+e^{ix}+\dots+e^{inx})
=-\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}\right).
$$
Next,
$$
-\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{ix}}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{2-2\cos(x)}
=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln(1-\cos(x))}{2}
$$
so
$$
\int_{\pi}^x -\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{ix}}\right) dx=
\left.-\frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}{2}\right|_\pi^x=\frac{\ln 2}{2}-\frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}{2}
$$
Consequently.
$$
S_n(x)-S_n(\pi)=
\int_{\pi}^x -\sum_{k=1}^n  \sin(kx) dx=\int_\pi^x
-\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}\right) dx.
$$
and at the same time
$$
S_n(\pi)=
-\left[1-\frac12+\frac13-\dots\pm \frac1n\right]=-\ln 2+O(1/n).
$$
Also for $0<y\le \pi$,
$$
\int_\pi^y \frac{e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}dx=\int_\pi^y \left[e^{i(n+1)x}+e^{i(n+2)x}+e^{i(n+3)x}+\dots \right]dx=
\left.\left[\frac{e^{i(n+1)x}}{n+1}+\frac{e^{i(n+2)x}}{n+2}+\frac{e^{i(n+3)x}}{n+3}+\dots \right]\right|_\pi^y
=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{e^{iky}}k+O(1/n)\to 0\text{ as } n\to\infty
$$
as a remаinder of a convergent series (see the reference in the comments above).
As a result,
$$
S_n(x)=S_n(\pi)+\int_{\pi}^x -\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{ix}}\right) dx+O(1/n)=-\frac{\ln 2}2-\frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}2+O(1/n)
$$
yielding
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (kx)}k=-\frac{\ln 2}2-\frac{\ln(1-\cos x)}2=-\ln(2\sin(x/2)).
$$

I believe the answer should be -ln|2sin(x/2)|, or else we will have some complex part when the argument is negative
